# mp4 video not playing on iphone

Tags: html, iphone, video, background, mp4

I have a mp4 video to automatically play on website, but it doesn't play on iphone.
Referring to other Q & A about the same issue, I added "playsinline" to the video tag.

However it doesn't seem to work and nothing is displayed on the screen of my iphone.

Could anyone help me find out what is wrong with my code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
        body {
            background: #ffffff;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        video {
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <video autoplay loop muted playsinline class="video-background ">
        <source src="video01.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try using Javascript to start playback when everything loaded.

Comment: Thank you, VC.One. It seems the format of mp4 file was not appropriate for the video to play on iphone. I changed the format and and now it works.

Comment: I'm having the same issue but I don't know what format to change the .mp4 to, could you tell me what you did to get it to work?

Comment: `@Jacob Buller`  Sorry for my late response. In my case,  I changed the "type" of the mp4 to "H.264／AVC" from "MPEG4" and it successfully played on my iphone. It seems "MPEG4" mp4 video won't play on some browsers. You can check your video type through MediaInfo(https://mediaarea.net/ja/MediaInfo). Hope this will help.