# <video tag is not working in iPhone with php headers

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, video, response-headers

I am using the following video code, which is not working in iPhone. I am checking if a user is login then displaying video using video_url.php file.

```
<video poster="path/poster-image.png" controls="controls" width="500" height="300"><source src="/path/video_url.php" type="video/mp4"><source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>
```

I am using the following code in "video_url.php". it is working for web/android but NOT for iPhone.

```
$vfn = '/path/vodep.mp4'; // Get video file from 
header("Content-Type: video/mp4");
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($vfn));
readfile($vfn);
```

Comment: https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/unable-to-play-embedded-mp4-videos-on-ipad-or-iphone-in-confluence-305037325.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55701447/mp4-video-not-playing-on-iphone

Comment: In other words, check the file format of your video is compatible

Comment: (Just FYI, any such implementation that does not support range requests, is a rather epic, massive “fail” to begin with.)